# angularjs show with animation on true and hide after delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

```html
<div ng-show="IsError">ERROR !!</div>
<button ng-click="validate()">Validate</button>
```

```
function MainController($scope, ) {
    $scope.IsError = false;

    $scope.validate = function (val) {
        $scope.IsError = true;
        setTimeout(function () {
            $scope.IsError = false;
        }, 1500);
    }
}
```

On validate() **div** show but not hide.

1. How show **div** hide after 1.5 sec with angular (no DOM manipulate)?
2. How animate show and hide with transparent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$timeout service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) like below:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$timeout) {
  $scope.IsError = false;

    $scope.validate = function (val) {
        $scope.IsError = true;
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.IsError = false;
        }, 1500);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div ng-show="IsError">ERROR !!</div>
<button ng-click="validate()">Validate</button>
</div>
```